# Unable to activate Bootstrap popup through AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `angularjs` in my project. I want to use a `bootstrap popover` which would show up when user clicks on a link. The popover is supposed to show an input field where the user is supposed to enter some words.

```
<span style="font-size:14px; word-wrap: break-word;" ng-bind-html="linkifyWord(message.expert_advice)"> </span>
```

Now the function `linkifyWord` is defined in `index.js` which basically makes certain words in a string as a [link](https://google.com) and sends the string back containing html in it.

**original sentence:** number of incidents by type for lopa

The string returned by `linkifyWord` containing html is below

```
number of <a href='#' data-html='true' data-toggle='popover' rel='popover' title=problems,issues data-content="<p> <input type='text'/> </p> <p> <input type='submit' value='Submit'/> </p>"> incidents </a> by <a href='#' data-html='true' data-toggle='popover' rel='popover' title=categories,nature data-content="<p> <input type='text'/> </p> <p> <input type='submit' value='Submit'/> </p>"> type </a> for lopa
```

So the end result should look like this

number of [incidents](https://google.com) by [type](https://google.com) for lopa

As you can see above, it makes two words as links. Now I am not going to share the exact logic of how do I convert a regular sentence into the one above as it involves calling some apis, getting data, processing it and so on.

Now I am able to ge the output above. But what should happen next is, when you click on the link, a `popup` should appear which contains an `input field` where user can enter some message and hit `submit`. But I am not able to get the `popup`. I am basically using a `bootstrap popup`.

I have all the imports necessary to use `Bootsrap` in my project. I will share the import below just so you guys can check

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The interesting part is when I try to run this in an online compiler like `jsfiddle`, I get the expected popups. Here is the link below

http://jsfiddle.net/retkza54/

Then why doesn't it work in my system? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `bootstrap.js` code does not play well with the AngularJS framework. Consider using a third-party library like [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.

Comment: UI-Bootstrap exists for a reason, jQuery should not be used with Angular.